# Bing AJAX Map: Show Info Box firing before Map Zoom and Pan has ended

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net, ajax, bing-maps

In my Bing Ajax Map app the user is presented with a list of locations they can choose from. OnRowClick the map center and zooms on that places location. After it has focused on that location, it shows the info window for it as well.

The problem is that the info window seems to be loading before the map has finished panning. This causes the info window to appear in the wrong spot, or not at all. For now I've put the show info method in a setTimeout tag to give it another second before loading the information, but its a fairly ugly hack and still doesn't work 100% of the time.

Has anybody else run into this problem before? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Kosko

Answer (score 0):

You're centering and zooming on the clicked location. Is it possible that the window you're loading can go in the same place every time, since you know where the location you've clicked will be once it's done panning (i.e. the center of the map)?

That way the window can appear while the map is panning without causing any problems.